# google drive: script send email when a cell is filled

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

im trying to make my 1st steps into google drive to solve a problem of automating a notification email when a certain cell is filled, I would really appreaciate if somebody can show me the path to make this functionality work.

Comment: please take a look first to the documentation. see google apps script triggers. come back with some code if you still are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The particular things you are looking for in the docs are examples of `onEdit()` scripts and triggers in Spreadsheets, along with either `GmailApp` or `MailApp` to send mail.

In short you can have an `onEdit()` function which checks what cell was changed, and if you care send a mail. If this sends too much mail, you might instead record to-be-sent changes to a second tab, and have a time-based tigger for another function which sends any pending mail once/twice/thrice per hour/day/week.